# Is it possible to prevent page change from Href on specific conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

As the title said, Is it possible to prevent page change from Href for a specific condition.

For example; if i have a div

```
<div href="#nextpage.html">Click me</div>
```

Is it possible to set a if statement to only allow a certain condition for this div to go to the nextpage??

For example

```
var canclick ="can_click";

if(canclick=="can_click"){

// Then allow the href to process to the next page.
} else {

// Have an alert up to say that the user can not proceed to the next page. And prevent the href to move to the next page. 
}
```

Edit

```
 $("#anchor").on('click', function(e) { 

 alert("clicked2");

})
```

Edit:

The only way the click event is

```
    <a href="#nextpage.html" onClick="clicked();"></a>

function clicked(){
alert(detected);

}
```

Edit:
I also just tried these. None of the alert gets called.

```
 if($("#anchor").data('clicked'))
{
alert("again clicked");
}    
             $("#anchor").on('click', function(e) { 

 var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('clicked')) {
       alert("clicked");
    }

})
```

Comment: So i add on a click event to it?? A on('click',function(){}?? And then put the if statement inside and tag the click event to an id for that div???

Comment: Yes, `$('div[href]').on('click', function() { window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); });`

Comment: Sweet thanks, i will give it a try right now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example.  The click function is not triggered if the initial condition is met (`i = 0`).  Then, click the link again, and `i != 1`, so the normal `<a>` navigation is allowed to proceed.

```js
i = 0;

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  if (i == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('i = 0');
  } else {
    alert('i = ' + i);
  }
  i++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="//stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thats what i tried... but for some very odd reason, the anchor tag isnt even detecting the click.... i am not sure if it is because its dynamically generated after the page is loaded... but it shouldnt have any effect on that right??

Comment: If it's dynamically loaded, you'll need to do something like `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {` .  The click function needs to be bound to an element that exists on page load.  See edit above.

Comment: I think its slowly working, still fixing it up but now its detecting the click!

Comment: Good.  If it's an `a` element, you only need to provide for `preventDefault()` if the condition is met - otherwise, just let it behave as `a` elements normally do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you do something similar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#enable").is(":checked")) {
      window.location = e.href;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input id="enable" name="check" type="radio" value="Enable" />Enable
  <br>
  <input id="disable" name="check" type="radio" value="Disable" />Disable
  <br/>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi i made an edit above(I just put a simple click event to detect if that anchor tag is clicked, but it isnt getting detected), i tried the suggestions, my other anchor tags are getting detected when on click, but the one i wished to get click isnt. I added an id="anchor" to detect it. But it isnt getting detected.

Comment: Try calling `e.stopPropagation()` after calling `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: The click function won't even get detected. The only way for me to get the click function to be detected is i added a onClick="clicked();" in the anchor tag.... But it still moves to the next page. Is there anyway for me to prevent page transition, within a function??